# Batch file on usb drive

Tags: usb-flash-drive

I'm trying to create a batch file that will run from a usb drive that copies files and folders from the host pc then creates a folder on the usb drive with the users name and then paste the files and folders in that folder. Can anyone may suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This fits closely to what you are looking for and will be a good start:
      http://www.paulski.com/zpages.php?id=1624

There is documentation that you can follow to setup your usb for autodownload of specific files.

Goodluck!